# NSPredicate with to-many relationship

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, nspredicate

I have a one-to-many relationship between two models, `user <-->> followers`, the followers table consists of `userId`s. I want to make a fetch request to get the associated users to theese `userId`s. My predicate currently looks like this:

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY userId IN %@", self.user.followers];
```

This results in 0 results. I wonder how this predicate should look like?

**Update**

The code I use for adding follower objects to user's (from JSON data):

```
+ (void)insertFollowersFromDict:(NSDictionary *)dictionary forUser:(User *)user  inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)moc
{
    NSArray *followers = [dictionary objectForKey:@"data"];

    if (followers.count != 0) {
        NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Follower" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
        for (NSString *followerId in followers) {
            Follower *newFollower = [[Follower alloc] initWithEntity:entityDescription insertIntoManagedObjectContext:moc];
            NSNumberFormatter * numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
            newFollower.user = [User findUser:[numberFormatter  numberFromString:followingId] inManagedObjectContext:moc];
            [user addFollowersObject:newFollower];
        }
    }
}
```

Code I use to configure cells in my tableview:

```
// This for some reason always result in the same user. 
Follower *follower = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
User *cellUser = follower.user;

// Always self.user
cell.text = cellUser.name

------------------------
I Anders               I
------------------------
------------------------
I Anders               I 
------------------------
```

I'm not sure why this happens.

Comment: @flexaddicted Thanks and yes. Also, see my edit, do you think that could be related?

Comment: Anders, sorry I removed my comment. IMHO, @Levi's reply is on the right track.

Comment: Do you need to display the name of the user or the followers?

Comment: I need to display the name of the followers.

Comment: I added an edit for you. Hope it is clear.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But wouldn't that lead to a lot of redundancy? Isn't there another way, do you think making it many-to-many could help?

Comment: See my edit. And yes as I suggested in my original answer. Hope that helps. Cheers.

Comment: Anders, did you find a way to fix your problem? Did many-to-many help? Do you still need help? Have a nice day. ;)

Comment: @flexaddicted Thanks for your patience! :) I'm trying the many-to-many way now. I'm wondering if I really need the `Follower` table? Couldn't the `User` have a relationship to itself? I'm trying that now, and it seems like `po self.user.followers`prints out the right users, but I'm still struggeling a bit with the predicate. Thanks, you too!

Comment: Maybe yes, but it really depends on what is the nature of your app. For having suggestions on how the model should look like I would open another question. Simply describe your goal (an app where users can follow each other) and ask for the more suitable model for this type of app. Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok, yes. Good idea, I will probably do that. Will give you the right answer, it was very good, helpful and correct for my original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anders,

I'll try to provide some details about the model I think is well suitable for let your app working.

First, your model should look like the following (I skipped attributes, as you can see).

[image]

An `User` is linked to zero or many `Follower`s.

Let me know discuss about relationships.

`followers` is a to-many relationship to `Follower` entity. It is set like this.

[image]

As you can see, the rel is **optional** since an user cannot have any follower. The delete rule is **cascade** since if you delete an user, also its followers will be deleted.

`user` on the contrary is to-one rel to an user. It looks like this.

[image]

It's not **optional** since a follower can exist only with an user. It's **nullify** since if you delete a follower, the change will no have effect to the associated user.

**NOTE** I created the model based on the specs you provide, but I think it could also be extended to fit a many-to-many relationship. This means: different users can have the same followers.

Now, if you create a fetch request against `Follower`, you can retrieve all the followers that belong to a specific user in the following way.

```
NSFetchRequest* request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Follower"]
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user == %@", self.user]];
NSArray* results = // execute the request here

// results will contain the followers for a specific user (i.e. the one you used in the predicate)
```

Hope that helps.

**Edit**

```
NSManagedObject* follower = [followerResults objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; // this gives you a follower, put some error control if followerResults has no elements
NSManagedObject* user = [follower objectForKey:@"user"]; // this gives you the user associated to that follower
```

**Edit 2**

I have no clear what you mean but the behavior is correct since you are using

```
cell.text = cellUser.name
```

In this way you retrieve the name associated to the user. **There is only one user associated to that set of followers**.

e.g. user Andrew has zero or many followers (Mike, Bob, Todd).

The fetch request you use does the following: **Give me all the followers where the user is Andrew.**

If you want to display the followers change like

```
cell.text = follower.name; // if Follower entity has a name attribute
```

**VERY VERY VERY IMPORTANT**

Add a new attribute (NOT a relationship) to your `Follower` entity. Called it `name` and make it of type `NSString`. As you did for the `User` entity (I suppose).

Then, when you create a new `Follower` object you will set it like

```
 newFollower.user = // set the user
 newFollower.name = // set the name
```

I really suggest to understand the difference bewteen **ATTRIBUTES** and **RELATIONSHIPS**.

The former are properties of a specific entity (e.g. name, age, gender). The latter are links among entities.

Comment: Thank you and @Levi too, the thing I missed before was that it returned all the followers as a set. Good and comprehensive answer! One releated question, if I get all the followers as a set how can I retrevie the right user in for example `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`?

Comment: @Anders I added an edit for you. Please check the code because I've written by hand. If this question (or Levi's one) completes your understanding of the scenario, you should think to offer the bounty and mark the answer as correct. Have a nice day. ;)

Comment: Thank you. I'm still having some trouble. The tableview lists `self.user` (but the right count of cells). I've added a edit to my original question.

Comment: Sorry  I cannot understand your comment. Could you provide more details in your **question**?

Comment: In particular, what do you mean with *The tableview lists self.user*?

Answer (score 3):

You should have a relationship between objects. You don't have to store the `userID` in the `Follower` object. This way you can simply write:

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user = %@", self.user];
```

This would return all the `Followers` that have a relationship to `self.user`. Hope this helps.

Comment: So you mean that the User model should have a relationship with it self (in your example called user)?

Comment: @Anders Yes, this is called inverse relationships and you should always have inverse relationships. Core Data uses them to maintain graph integrity.

Comment: +1 for your reply. It is nice. My previous comment was focused on the syntax of IN clause but you got the point here.

Comment: Your `User` type object should have a `followers` property of type `NSSet`, and your `Follower` object should have a `user` property of type `User`. If you have this, you make an `NSFetchRequest` with the entity `Follower`. That expression in the predicate basically means, that you want every existing `follower` that has it's `user` property equal to `self.user`.

Comment: Didn't get it to work. Doesn't your example return 1 user that is equal to self.user? Which is 0 in my Follower table.

Comment: Nope. Cause you set the `NSFetchRequest`'s entity to `Follower`. So it will return follower objects that has the same user as `self.user`